# Focus first empty input inside html form in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, angularjs-directive, directive

I am trying to focus first empty input inside a html form using angularjs directive. Here is the directive code which I have written so far (and applied on form element):

```
.directive('focusFirstEmptyInput', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var focustElement = function () {
                    var keepGoing = true;
                    angular.forEach(element[0], function (field) {
                        if (!keepGoing) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (field.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input')
                            return;

                        debugger;
                        var fieldValue = field.value;
                        if (!fieldValue) {
                            field.focus();
                            keepGoing = false;
                        }
                    });
                };

                $timeout(focustElement, 0);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I am iterating over all form elements and trying to focus first empty field. However, when I am calling focus(), element doesn't get focused. What can be the reason?

**UPDATE:**

Weird, but if I remove the debugger statement (or don't open inspector mode at all) and don't pause the javascript code, it will focus first empty element.... (I am using Google Chrome)

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YT0DoTjUVrrnVwmyrX0v?p=preview

Comment: I added plunker as well. But, I figured out the problem. Check update section.

Comment: The break point impacting it makes me think it's a race condition...  which means its not guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 2):

You have the timeout in the wrong place.  You could use jquery to do some of the lifting.  I'm not sure how to filter on empty inputs, so used a for loop (someone please improve this).

Add this directive to your module, then add the attribute "focus-first" on the parent element you want it to set focus for.

```
.directive('focusFirst', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {            
        return {                
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                    
                $timeout(function() {
                    var inputs = element.find('input'),
                        count = inputs.length;

                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        if (inputs[i].value) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        inputs[i].focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }, 0);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a test and seems to be the 0 value in the $timeout. Change it to 300 or something similar. With 300 work either you have developer tools open or not.

Works for me.